# S6 Edge stuck at Samsung logo

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6

After a walk outside I came in to see that my S6 edge shows the logo and tries to start, but it doesn't. It is a blinking logo.

Any ideas how I can get it to start up normally again?

Comment: Was your phone connected to the charger?

Comment: What about hard reboot? pressing your power key for 5-10 sec.

Comment: Not connected to the charger at the time. hard reboot did not work(in the sense that it did not restart and it hasn't before by pressing the power key. tested it when I got the phone to know how to restart if something happens.)